# KendoUI Combobox responsivenes

Tags: kendo-ui

I am working with the Kendo UI beta (v. 2013.1.226) and I found that there are some glitches when you change the font size of a combobox.

The drpodown arrow doesn't seem right - it is a bit up while it shouold perfectly position itself in the center of the dropdown button.

To illistrate - I am attaching a screenshot.
Anyone know if there's a way to fix this? 
I am thinking of somehow change the x and y position of the background to be relative.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

**Update:** Not quite sure if it's only me but found another problem changing the font size, the list seems to overlap the input field as shown in the second image:

[image]

I am using IE 9. Anyone have those problems or is it just me?
As far as I know Kendo shouldn't be interfering with other styles on the page (the styles start with k- prefix) so I am wondering if the issues only occur for me or are common.

Answer (score 1):

The KendoUI Combobox is made up of multiple components and has its own styling for all the parts including the arrow. The arrow is actually two nested spans in the version I am using (2013.1.514).

I changed my textbox heights and got different alignment problems:

[image]

I would not expect the supplied KendoUI CSS to survive a font-size change as they are tweaked to look good at its own default font size. Your best bet is to use Chrome's F12 tools to determine what CSS styles are affected and tweak the Kendo styles (or your overrides) to match your requirements.